# Menu Button in Gtk3 Vala Application

Tags: gtk3, vala, gtkbuilder

I am trying to make a Gtk3 Application with vala.

I am using a ui-file for Interface design. I can find no information on how to do this GMenu(?) with a ui file. There are lots of examples for coding this in vala.

How can I add this Menu Button in my ui file?

You can find the full code on [github.com](https://github.com/zege-at/ZeiterfassungGtk/blob/master/src/window.ui)

I want this type of Menu for my app:
[image: Screenshot of expected Menu Button]
The only thing I can do is this:
[image: Screenshot of actual Menu Button]

This is my ui-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object class="GtkPopoverMenu" id="popovermenu1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      <child>
        <placeholder />
      </child>
  </object>

  <template class="ZeiterfassunggtkWindow" parent="GtkApplicationWindow">
    <property name="default-width">600</property>
    <property name="default-height">300</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <object class="GtkHeaderBar" id="header_bar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="show-close-button">True</property>
        <property name="title">Zeiterfassung</property>
        <property name="subtitle">Precisma GmbH</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuButton">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="popover">popovermenu1</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder />
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLabel" id="label">
        <property name="label">Hello, World!</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <attributes>
          <attribute name="weight" value="bold"/>
          <attribute name="scale" value="2"/>
        </attributes>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>
```

**Solution:**
Found the answer with the help of Jens:

I had to add a icon als GtkImage at the bottom of the template after `</template>`

```
<object class="GtkImage" id="menu_image">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="icon_name">open-menu-symbolic</property>
</object>
```

Then use this GtkImage for the Button:

```
      <object class="GtkMenuButton">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="popover">popovermenu1</property>
        <property name="image">menu_image</property>
        <child>
          <placeholder />
        </child>
      </object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `Gtk.MenuButton` with `use_popover = True`, see the gedit source code here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/gedit/resources/ui/gedit-window.ui#L93

```
<object class="GtkMenuButton" id="gear_button">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="valign">center</property>
  <property name="use_popover">True</property>
  <property name="image">menu_image</property>
</object>
<packing>
  <property name="pack_type">end</property>
</packing>
```

Also note that the button is inside a `Gtk.HeaderBar` component.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Never thought of looking in the gedit source ;). All i was missing was the icon. Found it in the gedit Source. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, I didn't even see the "image" property, glad you found it.

Comment: @GeraldZehetner What do you mean, you found the icon? You mean, you found the three-line image file? On my computer, all GTK applications show a three-dot icon for that. Doesn't it mean that it is part of the system resource? So, can I specify that resource instead of adding my own image? If so, how to set that icon within Glade? I cannot find a property for icon for a GtkMenuButton.

Comment: @GeraldZehetner Well, seeing the code, the icon name is `open-menu-symbolic`. The code is using "image" property, but I could not get that working, so I added a child GtkImage instead.